# How to access global variable inside method in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement a LinkedList with an add method. As you can see, I've created a LinkedList class and initialized it with a `nodes` attribute that's an `ArrayList` containing `String`s.

The `add` function should simply take a value and append it to the end of `nodes`. Instead, I'm getting a NullPointerException.

What am I missing here?

```
public class LinkedList {
  public static ArrayList<String> nodes;

  public LinkedList() {
    ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.print(nodes);
  }

  public ArrayList<String> add(String value) {
    nodes.add(value);
    return nodes;
  }


  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
  {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("B");
  }

}
```

Comment: Can I ask why `nodes` is static? `nodes` is part of the instance, not class. Also, it should be `nodes = new ArrayList<String>();` without the type since it's already a field.

Comment: `ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();` this is the problem.

Comment: Your local variable is hiding a field.  Did your compiler not warn you about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having 2 variables for the same job. A static `nodes` variable that is not initialized, hence the NullPointerException. And another local `nodes` variable inside the class constructor that gets initialized but never used.

To use a single `nodes` variable in an OOP way follow these 2 steps to fix your issues:

1. Remove `static` from `public static ArrayList<String> nodes;` to have a proper instance variable.
2. Change `ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();` to `nodes = new ArrayList<String>();` to initialize that instance variable